# lINUX PYTHON not found error

Tags: python

Run python as a process with this command: nohup python app.py & --port=4650
If everything is fine, and server is working, process will exit without any errors.

I am getting a error on --port=4650, saying "not found"

Why is this wrong ???

Comment: Why down-vote without providing a comment? How are we supposed to know what we did wrong if we don't get feedback why we did something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shell, `&` is a a command separator (like `;`). You're asking the shell to run two separate commands:

- `nohup python app.py &`
- `--port=4650`

Make sure the `&` is always at the end of your command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit fuzzy on this part of the command line, but I believe this runs app.py in Python and puts it in the background:

```
nohup python app.py &
```

Then, I believe this is attempted as a separate command, which obviously doesn't exist:

```
--port=4650
```

I suspect you want to run this instead:

```
nohup python app.py --port=4650 &
```

This is assuming your app.py is written to accept a --port argument.